# Validating user with azure active directory using their email and password in asp.net core web

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to login staff with the Azure active directory to the application I am working on(An dotNet core web api).

I have seen where staffs just use their Azure AD credential to log in to the asp.net applications.

But this is my first time working with Azure active directory.

I have implemented this below, with this I could get a token and then use that to access protected routes. also, I could get the user object and see the department they belong to.

I am getting this error below

```
Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access 'api://......
```

I have tried searches all over the internet and Stackoverflow. non has given me a definite answer.

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
               options.Audience = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Audience"];
               options.Authority = $"{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";
           });
```

AuthController

```
 [HttpPost(Name = "Login")]
        public ActionResult<string> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var authority = $"{_configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{_configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";

                var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"])
                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                    .Build();

                var scopes = new[] { _configuration["AzureAd:Audience"] };

                var result = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, email, password).ExecuteAsync().Result;

                return "";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

To authenticate a user without triggering MFA requirements?

Comment: I don't know how as well, just have some questions. It looks like you are using ROPC flow which is not a recommended flow by Microsoft. And is it possible for you to use Azure Identity in your asp.net core web app? In the meantime, just want to double confirm, have you [enabled MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-azure-mfa) ?

Comment: Yes MFA is enabled

Comment: hmmm then I'm afraid it's impossible to authenticate a user without triggering MFA...

Comment: What other approach do you suggest?

Comment: tbh, I don't have any ideas about it...

Answer (score 0):

Use the interactive way of sign in, as this mostly occurs due to the non-interactive way.

In the following code , check if scopes are given the right way.

In the below code that you provided, scopes are configured to be audience which is most probably in `api://clientId` format.

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Login")]
        public ActionResult<string> Login(string email, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var authority =
                      ....
                var scopes = new[] { _configuration["AzureAd:Audience"] };
                var result =
            ...
 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

But the scope must be in format of: **`api://<clientId>/<scopeName>`** or **`api://<clientId>/.defaul`**t for client credential flow. In case of calling microsoft graph api it must be **`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`**

Include necessary scopes like openid for example:

```
var scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "openid" , "offline_access", "Files.Read" };
```

**appsetting.json:**

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    // "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx",
    "Domain": "testxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "xxx",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientSecret": "xxx",
    Audience": "50065a5f-d3e4-426f-a4f4-1e6fbd2ed06e",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    //"Scopes": "api://5xxxxe/access_as_user"
    "Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    //"Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read''"
  }
```

Also if you are an admin check if security defaults for your tenant are being applied automatically to the new service principal . see [Providing a default level of security in Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults)

[image]

[image]

The guest user can  login with correct tenant id if multiple tenants are there.

```
az login --tenant <tenantid>
```

In your case:

```
az login --tenant 42531xxxxxx74ef
```

[image]

Other wise the only cause might be admin changing the conditional access policy for users from particular location or device.Reach out to admin to change the access policy for that particular application and user.